Could a principal ideal be maximal in $k[X_1, X_2]$?
Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, and $\mathfrak{a} \subset k[X_1, X_2]$ an ideal generated by a single polynomial $f(X_1, X_2) \in k[X_1, X_2]$. Could $\mathfrak{a}$ possibly be maximal in $k[X_1, X_2]$? Will the answer be different if we force $f$ to be monic in $X_1$ or $X_2$? (By saying that $f$ be monic in $X_1$, I mean it is monic in $(k[X_2])[X_1]$, the ring of polynomials in one variable over $k[X_2]$.)
Note: This question came up when I try to learn the connection between integral dependence and weak Nullstellensatz.

Another reason that this is impossible is that if $A$ is a finitely generated algebra over a field and $p\subset A$ is a prime ideal, then $\dim A/p = \dim A - \operatorname{ht} p$, but a field has Krull dimension zero and the height of a prime ideal generated by one element is bounded above by one by Krull's Hauptidealsatz.

More generally, if $k$ is any field, and $I$ is a maximal ideal in $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, then $I$ can be generated by $n$ elements, but not by fewer than $n$ elements. See this MathOverflow post from Pete L. Clark.

@KReiser Thank you. I am just a beginner in Commutative Algebra, so Krull dimension seems a too advanced tool for me. Still, thank you for your comment.

@Joe Thank you. I wonder if there are some more 'elementary' ways to show this result? It seems that most answers in your link resort to Krull dimension.

@zyy: I don't know enough commutative algebra to give you a definitive answer, but I suspect that it is not possible to give an elementary proof of the above fact. Most of the results in commutative algebra with this kind of "flavour" seem to have an inherent kind of difficulty attached to them. (On the other hand, it is perhaps possible to give an elementary answer to your original question.) That being said, although many of the results in commutative algebra concerning Krull dimension are nontrivial, the definition of Krull dimension itself is fairly easy to understand. [Cont...]

Basically, given a commuative ring $R$ we can consider "chains" of proper inclusions of prime ideals $\mathfrak p_0\subsetneq \mathfrak p_1\subsetneq\dots\subsetneq \mathfrak p_n$. The length of such a chain is defined to be $n$, i.e. the number of proper inclusions rather than the number of ideals. The Krull dimension of $R$ is simply the supremum of all the lengths of chains of prime ideals in $R$. Examples: $\mathbb Z$ has dimension one, a field has dimension zero, and the trivial ring has dimension $-\infty$ (!).

@Joe Thank you. I have also checked out Krull dimension in wikipedia. I think the definition is intuitive in that it is similar to the length of composition series of groups and vector spaces, but it is not so intuitive why the ideals in the chain should be restricted to prime ideals.

@Joe Also, I have written down a (seemingly correct) elementary proof of my original question below. Would you please be so kind to check it for me?

@zyy: Unfortunately, I can't give you a detailed explanation about why we restrict to prime ideals, but the motivation behind the Krull dimension is for it to align with what "dimension" means intuitively means for geometric objects. A curve should have dimension one, a surface should have dimension two, etc. The dimension of an algebraic set $X\subseteq\mathbb A_k^n$ (which can be defined in many different ways) is the Krull dimension of the coordinate ring $k[X]=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I(X)$ (the coordinate ring is isomorphic to the ring of polynomial functions defined on $X$).

I will have a look at your proof later.

@Joe Thank you. I think I have to learn more geometry in order to understand the geometric motivation behind the Krull dimension. But I think Krull himself may have developed this idea purely from algebra, since he seems to focus mainly on commutative ring theory. Anyway, thank you for your explanation.

The answer is no. Actually, it will be no over any field, we don't even have to restrict ourselves to the algebraically closed case. Let $f\in k[x,y]$ be a non constant polynomial. Assume $(f)$ is a maximal ideal, and let $K=k[x,y]/(f)$. Then $K$ is a field that can be naturally seen as an extension of $k$. It is clearly finitely generated as an algebra over $k$, and by a well known theorem (that is often used to prove the Nullstellensatz) it follows that $K$ is also finitely generated as a vector space over $k$. This means $K/k$ is a finite field extension, and in particular algebraic.
Now, without loss of generality assume that $f$ is not constant in the variable $x$, and consider the coset $y+(f)\in K$. This element is algebraic over $k$, and so we have an equality of the form:
$(y+(f))^n+a_{n-1}(y+(f))^{n-1}+...+a_1(y+(f))+(a_0+(f))=0+(f)$
where $a_0,...,a_{n-1}\in k$. But this equality can be rewritten as follows:
$y^n+a_{n-1}y^{n-1}+...+a_1y+a_0+(f)=(f)$,
which means that $f$ divides the polynomial $y^n+a_{n-1}y^{n-1}+...+a_1y+a_0$. But this is a contradiction, as $f$ is not constant in the variable $x$, and so it can't divide a nonzero polynomial that is constant in $x$.

Thank you, Mark. I think 'the well known theorem that is often used to prove the nullstellensatz' is called Zariski's lemma, which can also been viewed as a corollary of the famous Noether's normalization lemma. I was actually trying to develop a proof of weak Nullstellensatz in the case of two variables, where I hoped I could avoid using these two lemma. As a step toward this end, I tried to prove that a principal ideal must not be maximal, but it seems that to prove this result one still needs Zariski's lemma or Noether's nomalization lemma.

@zyy Yeah, this theorem can be proved using Noether's normalization. (though there are also direct proofs) Sometimes it is indeed called Zariski's lemma, I forgot that.

Mark, I have written down a (seemingly correct) elementary proof below. Would you please be so kind to check it for me?

It seems that I have found a relatively elementary proof in the case  $k$ is infinite (in particular, the case $k$ is algebraically closed). I am not confident about my reasoning, so it would be so kind for anyone to point out the gap in my proof.
Assume that $(f)$ is maximal so that $K=k[x,y]/(f)$ is a field. Assume W.L.O.G. that $f$ is not constant in $Y$, and $f(X, Y) = f_n(X) Y^n + f_{n-1} (X) Y^{n-1} + \dots + f_0(X)$, where $\deg f_n(X) = d$.
Consider the set $S = \{X-c: c\in k\}$. Since $f$ is not constant in $Y$, we can pick out $T = \{X-c_i: i = 1, \dots, d+1\}\subset S$ such that $T \cap (f) = \varnothing$. Because $K$ is a field, $X-c_i + (f)$ is invertible for $i\in I$
$\implies$ $\prod_{i}(X-c_i) +(f)$ is invertible
$\implies$ $g(X,Y)\prod_{i}(X-c_i) -1 = f(X,Y)h(X,Y)$ for some $g,h\in k[X,Y]$
$\implies$ $f(c_i, Y)h(c_i, Y) = -1$ for $i = 1, \dots, d+1$.
$\implies$ $f_n(c_i) = 0$ for $i = 1, \dots, d+1$,
which contradicts $\deg f_n(X) = d$.
Note: It seems that the same construction occurs in another proof here. I have not gone through it, but I think this enhances the credibility of my proof.
